# Using awk to count the number of occurrences of a word in a column

Tags: linux, bash, awk

```
03/03/2014 12:31:21 BLOCK 10.1.34.1 11:22:33:44:55:66

03/03/2014 12:31:22 ALLOW 10.1.34.2 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF

03/03/2014 12:31:25 BLOCK 10.1.34.1 55:66:77:88:99:AA
```

I am trying to use awk to count the number of occurrences of the word "block" and "access" above in one command.

I tried the word "block" at first but my counter does not appear to be working. Can anyone see where my code is wrong?

```
awk ' BEGIN {count=0;}  { if ($3 == "BLOCK") count+=1} end {print $count}' firewall.log
```

Comment: Do you mean allow instead of access ?

Answer (score 58):

Use an array

```
awk '{count[$3]++} END {for (word in count) print word, count[word]}' file
```

If you want "block" specifically: `END {print count["BLOCK"]}`

Comment: Hi, how do I grep information base on count[word] ? For example, if i would like to grep the line which count[word] is more than 2. @glenn jackman

Comment: You would add an `if` statement into the `for` loop in the END block.

Comment: Can we check the Block word percentage ?

Comment: Yes we can. How would you start to do that?

Answer (score 38):

Here is a non-code solution. You can string together the steps with pipes ( "|" ).

```
awk '{print $3}' file | sort | uniq -c
```

- `awk '{print $3}'`

  print the 3rd column , the default record separator in awk is white space.
- `sort`

  sort the results
- `uniq -c`

  count the number repeated occurrences

Comment: Exactly what I needed. uniq was missing for me hehe :) P.S. sort -n is also good, natural sort.

Answer (score 8):

I tested your statement

```
awk ' BEGIN {count=0;}  { if ($3 == "BLOCK") count+=1} end {print $count}' firewall.log
```

and was able to successfully count `BLOCK` by doing two changes

1. `end` should be in caps
2. remove `$` from `print $count`

So, it should be:

```
awk ' BEGIN {count=0;}  { if ($3 == "BLOCK") count+=1} END {print count}' firewall.log
```

A simpler statement that works too is:

```
awk '($3 == "BLOCK") {count++ } END { print count }' firewall.log
```

Answer (score 7):

The reason that your code may not be working is `END` is case sensitive so your script will be checking the variable `end` exists(which it doesn't) and so the last block will never be executed.
If you change that then it should work.

Also you do not need the `BEGIN` block as all variable are instantiated at 0.

Below I have added an alternative way of doing this that you may want to use instead.

This is similar to glenn's but captures only the words you want, it should use little memory because of this.

---

Using Gawk(for the third arg of match)

```
awk 'match($3,/BLOCK|ALLOW/,b){a[b[0]]++}END{for(i in a)print i ,a[i]}' file
```

This block only executes if `BLOCK` or `ALLOW` are contained in the third field.
The match captures what has been matched into the array b.
Then array a is incremented for the matched field.

In the `END` block each captured field is outputted with a count of occurences.

---

The output is

```
ALLOW 1
BLOCK 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The error in your `awk` invocation is that, in your "END" block, you have `print $count`. That takes the content of the `count` variable, assumes it is an integer, and attempts to find the corresponding field in the last line of input. What you really want is just `print count`, as that just prints the value in the `count` variable. It's sometimes easy to mix up different variable referencing schemes between `bash`, `awk`, `python`, etc., so it's an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you just need to print count rather than $count. Inside awk, you do not need to use $ to find variable. In your case, the awk will try to print $2 before ending which does not exit. Below code should work:

`awk ' BEGIN {count=0;}  { if ($3 == "BLOCK") count+=1} END {print count}' firewall.log`