# Exporting data from shell as 2 seperate columns

Tags: shell, terminal

As it stands I have a very large set of data in my mac terminal that looks something like this:

```
0001   Jimbo    Random-tweet
0002   Jimbo    Random-tweet
0003   Doug     Another-random-tweet
0004   Charles  Another-random-tweet
```

Right now im using: `cut -f 2 Twitter_Data_1 |sort | uniq -c > Uniq.csv`

Which is gathering each unique user and how many tweets they've posted.
This is what it looks like in Uniq.csv

```
2 Jimbo
1 Charles
1 Doug
```

Only problem is that they're in the same column. I need them to be in seperate columns.

Is there a quick change to the code in order to achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show your records in separate columns in CSV all you need is `,` as delimiter instead of space , as in your current output.

To do so you can use `tr` command that would translate all spaces to `,`

```
cut -f 2 Twitter_Data_1 |sort | uniq -c | tr " " "," > Uniq.csv
```

OR using **awk**

```
cut -f 2 Twitter_Data_1 |sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $1","$2}' > Uniq.csv
```

or only using **awk**

```
awk '{a[$2]++}  END{for(i in a){print a[i]","i} }' Twitter_Data_1 > Uniq.csv
```

Output :

```
2,Jimbo
1,Charles
1,Doug
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command for your scenario,

```
awk '{cnt[$2]++} END {for (word in cnt) print cnt[word], word}' Twitter_Data_1 > Uniq.csv
```

duplicate question: [Using awk to count the number of occurrences of a word in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986425/using-awk-to-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-word-in-a-column)

Comment: Would you mind explaining it? What part of the code does the exporting to a seperate file?

Comment: I have updated "> Uniq.csv" content in end of the command which part of the code is exporting to the new file.