# Parsing the access logs

Tags: awk

```
xx.xx.xx.xx [04/Jun/2020:01:15:45 -0400] 179478 86841 www.abc.com 781 "POST /api/search?type=1234 HTTP/1.0" 200 "-" "IOS" 
xx.xx.xx.xx [04/Jun/2020:01:15:45 -0400] 179478 86841 www.abc.com 781 "POST /api/search?type=333 HTTP/1.0" 200 "-" "IOS" 
xx.xx.xx.xx [04/Jun/2020:01:15:45 -0400] 179478 86841 www.abc.com 781 "POST /api/search?type=1234 HTTP/1.0" 200 "-" "IOS" 
xx.xx.xx.xx [04/Jun/2020:01:15:45 -0400] 179478 86841 www.abc.com 781 "POST /api/search?type=333 HTTP/1.0" 200 "-" "IOS" 
xx.xx.xx.xx [04/Jun/2020:01:15:45 -0400] 179478 86841 www.abc.com 781 "POST /api/search?type=333 HTTP/1.0" 200 "-" "IOS"
```

Above are the my access logs.
Using ask comand  `awk '{ print $9 }'` i am able to get /api/search?type=1234, howver i am now stuck.

I am looking to get the counts of type

1234 = 3

333 = 2

Can some help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using awk to count the number of occurrences of a word in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986425/using-awk-to-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-word-in-a-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order isn't important, a quick use of `substr` using the `index` of `'='` (`+1`) incrementing an array using the result as the array index works, e.g.

```
$ awk '{a[substr($9, index($9,"=")+1)]++} END{ for (i in a) print i "=" a[i]}' log
333=3
1234=2
```

Above the array `a[]` uses `substr($9, index($9,"=")+1)` to extract what is to the right of `'='` in field 9 incrementing that element of the array each time a value is encountered.

Computing the `index` first and ensuring it is non-zero will allow you to exclude records where field 9 does not contain your `=[0-9]+` pattern, e.g.

```
$  awk '{ndx=index($9,"="); if(ndx) a[substr($9, ndx+1)]++} 
        END{ for (i in a) print i "=" a[i]}
' log
333=3
1234=2
```

The answer by [@RavinderSingh13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5866580/ravindersingh13) also validates the pattern before including the record using the return of `match` (nicely done)

(**note:** there are 3 occurrences of `333` and 2 occurrences of `1234` contrary to what you show as the counts)

---

**Edit per Comment re: Record Contains Non-Number Following =**

If you need to use a regex to match the location within the field, then `match()` is required, e.g.

```
$ awk '{ndx=match($9,/=[0-9]+/); if(ndx) a[substr($9, ndx+1)]++} 
  END{ for (i in a) print i "=" a[i]}' log
  333=3
  1234=2
```

`index` does not allow a regex constant as the `find` parameter. (except by non-standard extension)

Comment: I am looking for general soution and its not working for this url /api/version/not/trac?rid=abc:defas-dff

Comment: Yes, the `=` check was limited to  field 9, but I do not exclude non-numbers -- If your log contains non-numbers in that location, then `match()` as @RavinderSingh13 shows is required. `index` does not allow a regex constant as the `find` parameter. For example, you would replace `index($9,"=")` with `match($9,/=[0-9]+/)`

Answer (score 3):

***EDIT:*** Since user mentioned in comments that type keyword may not come always so adding more generic solution here.

```
awk '
match($0,/=[0-9]+/){
  array[substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)]++
}
END{
  for(i in array){
    print i,array[i]
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown example.

```
awk '
match($0,/type=[0-9]+/){
  array[substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5)]++
}
END{
  for(i in array){
    print i,array[i]
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `grep` + `cut` + `sort` + `uniq`, may not be as efficient as `awk` solution adding it as an alternative here.

```
grep -oP '.*\?type=\K.*' Input_file | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: I am looking for general soution and its not working for this url /api/version/not/trac?rid=abc:defas-dff

Comment: @SuhaanaaShah, Could you please do add more samples in your question too. Also please do let us know what is pattern to catch too.

Comment: @SuhaanaaShah, could you please check my edit solution and lemme know if that helped you?