# Counting the number of unique values based on two columns in bash

Tags: awk, cut, uniq

I have a tab-separated file looking like this:

```
A 1234
A 123245
A 4546
A 1234
B 24234
B 4545
C 1234
C 1234

Output: 
A 3
B 2
C 1
```

Basically I need counts of unique values that belong to the first column, all in one commando with pipelines. As you may see, there can be some duplicates like "A 1234".  I had some ideas with awk or cut, but neither of the seem to work. They just print out all unique pairs, while I need **count** of unique values from the second column considering the value in the first one.

```
awk -F " "'{print $1}' file.tsv | uniq -c
cut -d' ' -f1,2 file.tsv | sort | uniq -ci
```

I'd really appreciate your help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: sort + uniq and then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986425/using-awk-to-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-word-in-a-column)

Comment: Why are you using `cut -d' '` (i.e. telling `cut` to use a blank instead of a tab as the separator) when your file is tab-separated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With complete `awk` solution could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} !found[$0]++{val[$1]++} END{for(i in val){print i,val[i]}}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                  ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="\t"
}
!found[$0]++{       ##Checking condition if 1st and 2nd column is NOT present in found array then do following.
  val[$1]++            ##Creating val with 1st column inex and keep increasing its value here.
}
END{                   ##Starting END block of this progra from here.
  for(i in val){       ##Traversing through array val here.
    print i,val[i]     ##Printing i and value of val with index i here.
  }
}
'  Input_file          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still get something like: A 1234 2 // A 123245 1 // A 4546 1 etc.

Comment: @ta4le, it worked fine for me with given examples, could you please do lemme know if your actual Input_file is same as shown samples?

Comment: @ta4le, is your Input_file comma separated? Kindly confirm the same once.

Comment: no, it is more complicated but the semantics is the same: two columns, keys and multiple values for them. Tab separated

Comment: @ta4le, ok if its TAB separated then I made changes in my code where I made field separator as TAB kindly do check it once and lemme know then.

Comment: I suggest using `found[$0]` instead of `found[$1,$2]`

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk:

```
$ gawk -F\\t '{a[$1][$2]}END{for(i in a)print i,length(a[i])}' file
```

Output:

```
A 3
B 2
C 1
```

Explained:

```
 $ gawk -F\\t '{               # using GNU awk and tab as delimiter
    a[$1][$2]                  # hash to 2D array
 }
 END {                         
     for(i in a)               # for all values in first field
         print i,length(a[i])  # output value and the size of related array
 }' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sort -u file | cut -f1 | uniq -c
   3 A
   2 B
   1 C
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way, using the handy [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) utility:

```
$ datamash -g1 countunique 2 < input.txt
A   3
B   2
C   1
```

Requires the input file to be sorted on the first column, like your sample. If real file isn't, add `-s` to the options.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
cat file.tsv | sort | uniq | awk '{print $1}' | uniq -c | awk '{print $2 " " $1}'
```

It works for your example. (But I'm not sure if it works for other cases. Let me know if it doesn't work!)