# Count the number of errors in a file

Tags: awk

I am having a file called result.txt and in that result.txt file I am having as below pattern:

```
Statement                       | error         | Declaration      | file         | msg 
---                             | PQ            | *                | first.txt    | This is coming due to the file differences
---                             | PQ            | *                | second.txt   | This is a expected error
---                             | NS            | *                | brown.txt    | This errors need to be fixed from the source file
expected logic is extended      | TP            | *                | green.txt    | This is directly coming from the source file
unexpected logic is seen here   | TNP           | *                | red.txt      | This is coming from the output file 
extended logic expected         | CN            | *                | blue.txt     | This is a expected case
```

I need to show the output as what is the error and how many times that particular error got repeated and also the total count of all the errors at the end like below:

```
result.txt:
PQ : 2
NS : 1
TP : 1
TNP: 1
CN : 1
Total number of errors : 6
```

I tried the below code but I am not getting the desired output:

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in result.txt
do
echo "$d:";
awk '{ print $3 }' result.txt
echo "";
done
```

Comment: This is purely an problem with `awk`. Removing the bash tag thence

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using awk to count the number of occurrences of a word in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986425/using-awk-to-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-word-in-a-column)

Comment: @Inian No, actually my file pattern is a bit different.

Comment: You can work it out by figuring out how to use `|` as a delimiter in awk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another, similar approach, that simply uses brute-force for the output format opposed to setting the output-record-separator could be similar to:

```
awk -F'|' '
    NR > 1 { gsub(/ *$/,"",$2 ); a[$2]++ }
    END    { for (i in a) {
                 n = n + a[i]
                 printf "%-4s: %d\n", i, a[i]
             }
             printf "Total number of errors : %d\n", n}
' errors
```

Where for all records greater than 1 (not the headings record), remove all trailing spaces in field and add to array `a[]` and increment value at that element.

In the `END` rule, you just loop over all fields as indexes in the array outputting the symbol and number of associated errors. You sum the errors in that same loop in `n`.

**Example Use/Output**

With your input in the file `errors`, you can just select-copy the expression above and middle-mouse-paste in a terminal to check the result, e.g.

```
$ awk -F'|' '
>     NR > 1 { gsub(/ *$/,"",$2 ); a[$2]++ }
>     END    { for (i in a) {
>                     n = n + a[i]
>                     printf "%-4s: %d\n", i, a[i]
>                 }
>                 printf "Total number of errors : %d\n", n}
> ' errors
 CN : 1
 NS : 1
 PQ : 2
 TNP: 1
 TP : 1
Total number of errors : 6
```

(**note:** a leading space is left before each of the symbols in the output. If you do not want it there, then `substr()`  as used by @Cyrus will remove them without any fuss. Or you can simply remove all but a space from your `gsub()` regex.

The formatting is handled in the `printf()` format strings alone. But pay attention to the special variables noted with the like by @Cyrus. They can provide a shorter and much more elegant solution in complex cases.

Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=" \\| "; OFS=" : "} NR>1{gsub(/ +$/, "", $2); count[$2]++} END{for(j in count) printf("%-3s%s%d\n", j, OFS, count[j]); print "Total number of errors", NR-1 }' file
```

Output:

```
CN  : 1
NS  : 1
PQ  : 2
TNP : 1
TP  : 1
Total number of errors : 6
```

> `FS=" \\| "`: set input field separator to  `|`

> `OFS=" : "`: set output field separator to  `:`

> `NR>1`: Ignore first line

> `gsub(/ +$/, "", $2)`: Remove trailing spaces from column 2

> `count[$2]++`: Save column 2 as a key to a hash/associative array and increment its frequency as its value

> `for(j in count)`: Loop through hash `count` to output its content

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: @Cyrus I am getting the output like this :  **errors:
second.txt : 1
first.txt  : 1
green.txt : 1
blue.txt : 1
TNP   | *    : 1
brown.txt : 1
Total number of errors : 6** .

Comment: @Rama: I cannot reproduce that at the moment. Please upload your file somewhere and share the link here.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F"|" 'BEGIN{ getline }
           { a[$2]++ }
           END{ for(i in a){ print i, a[i]; s=s+a[i] }; 
                print "Total numer of errors", s}' result.txt
```

`F="|"`  set column separator to "|"

`BEGIN{ getline }` skip the header line

`a[$2]++`   count the values in column2, using array named `a`

`END{..}`  print the results.

Comment: Thanks, it is working perfectly, but BEGIN{ getline } is to skip first line, Can we also skip for the first two lines ?

Comment: @Rama: `BEGIN{ getline; getline }`